# Product Access for Partner Community

Tags: partner-communities, product

Did anybody have experience with enabling Partner Community users with create/edit access for Product objects. I know you can't assign these permissions using the  Partner Community Profile, but are there any good workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean Product records as I know of no way for someone to create a new sObject from a Community.

If you did mean records, because of the permissions required, the only way one could do this would be to create a "mirror" object and use triggers to pass record inserts and updates back and forth between the Partner Community and your Org. This would be something to do with great caution.

Comment: i meant to ask create/edit Object Permissions for Products to be completely correct in SFDC exact terminology. And thank you for the answer I was thinking about going that way.

Comment: Sharing restrictions would apply to editing Products in a Partner Community. The object simply isn't directly available to Partners. Access to OLI through Opp is as close as a Partner is going to get.

Comment: But the proxy object connecting the Create/Edit operations Partner does back and forth to Product would work in the system mode through triggers, as stated in the answer right?

Comment: That's correct. :)