# Granting access to Product records for Partner Community user

Tags: partner-communities, product, visibility

Related to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73053/product-access-for-partner-community), but slightly different perspective...

We have set up a Partner Community and inserted Product records. Product records do not have an owner, so you cannot manage the sharing etc.

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US), partner user have **read access to Products**.

He can access the Products tab, and he can see all Products associated to a Pricebook. From there, he can click through to the effective Product record:

[image: Pricebook]

Same thing applies when accessing Products from an Opportunity. He can select Add Product, choose the Pricebook and then add the Opportunity Product. From there, he can click through to the effective Product record:

[image: Opportunity]

However, we have created a lookup from Lead to Product, where a partner user is unable to fill this in since he cannot see any Products. Same thing when he accesses the Products tab: he sees no records.

So it looks like he can access Products through Pricebook, but not directly. Thus my question is:

**Is there any way to make Products directly visible to partner users, either through configuration or programmatically?**

Comment: In the partner users' profile, do they have read access to products enabled?

Comment: Yes, they have. Otherwise they would not see the Product regardless of the way to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case solved by **activating** all Products, since only system admins are able to view inactive Products.

(Although it still looks strange to me that I could access a non activated Product through manipulating the url)